# Learning Mathematics in a Second Language

Tags: soft-question, education

My first language is English, and since all of my formal education has been undertaken in the USA, I have learned mathematics entirely in the English language. However, I have spent a fair amount of time abroad and I speak two other foreign languages, quite proficiently, one of which is Bahasa Indonesia. While searching Wikipedia for several math topics today (in English), I decided to compare the answers in Indonesian. I was surprised to find how little information was given on the corresponding responses, here are a few examples: [Measure Theory](http://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukuran_%28matematika%29), [Abstract Algebra](http://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aljabar_abstrak), [Set Theory](http://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teori_himpunan). There are many more examples like these. I then compared these same topics in western languages such as Deutsch, French, Russian and Spanish and I found that there was a lot more to be said about these topics there (though I couldn't comprehend anything written there).

I am now asking myself how important is it to be able to study mathematics in our first language? I know that most mathematicians and scientists these days are able to speak English very well (at times better than native speakers) and often publish books in English. So, I wondered is it worth while to even try to expand scientific literature into different languages. Or, should people from other parts of the world just be forced to deal with the fact the the language of science and mathematics is English (or at least some other western language)?

I personally find it a bit disheartening to think that in order for someone in Indonesia (or any other country with a similar issue) to get a first class education in Mathematics they must first learn English, or another language. I would like to hear what other peoples point of view on this? Thanks!

Comment: [I think I misunderstood your question on first reading. It's not for advice, is it? Sorry.]

Comment: _Perhaps_ this would be better suited at http://academia.stackexchange.com. (E.g., [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/4798) shows _some_ resemblance.)

Comment: I once took a math course that was taught in English but for which the textbook was in French.  I don't know French, but the amount you need in order to read a math book is very little.  In particular, you don't need to know how to pronounce anything.

Comment: Wikipedia need not be representative of an underlying issue.  Wikipedia is driven entirely by its users.  There are far more users of the English wikipedia than there are of the Indonesian one (I say that without having any statistics at hand, but with full confidence).  It makes sense that information would be more widely available on the more widely used version.  Especially coupled with the prevalence of English within the mathematics community.

Comment: For my graduate thesis I had to go over the classic Lehrbuch der Algebra by Weber. I knew a little german before, but I needed some hefty help from dictionaries to make it work. I was surprised that's the it is done in many cases in the academy, in particular with important mathematical languages like russian, german or french, for which many paper have no translation. So don't be afraid of dictionaries, in particular with the web now, and while it'll take more time to cover something you'll have to dwell into it more deeply. That can't be bad.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I am sure of the validity of assumption about users of Wikipedia is true. I know that Wikipedia is driven entirely by its users, and therefore if no one bother to contribute to the Indonesian section (I am guilty), then It won't be developed. I just felt disappointed that others were less fortunate to have this information at hand.

Comment: @Transmissionfrom Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't know about academia.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Isn't English is a compulsory subject in most middle and high schools in Indonesia?

Comment: @DonAntonio "while it'll take more time to cover something you'll have to dwell into it more deeply." I agree with this very much so, when studying a book in Spanish I am more prone to look up a word than I am to do in English, which often leads to me having a more solid understanding of why the author chose the word in question. Whereas in English I often suppose I don't need to look up a word since it is common to me. However the context of words changes things so looking up words can really be beneficial.

Comment: @Transmissionfrom It is depends on which schools you pay to attend. Living there for six month would convinces me that a small percentage of the population could read technical articles in mathematics. (My view could be bias though)

Comment: @JimmyJackson Yes, but my point is that the English Wikipedia entries that you refer to _also_ require schooling (way) beyond that of the average English-speaking population.

Comment: @Transmissionfrom you have a good point there. Also,  many US citizens would prefer to never read those articles so it may be a waste of my time to translate these topics anyways. Although, I also find it disheartening that many US citizens could careless about mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Given(?) that English is (nowadays) a compulsory subject in most middle and high schools in Indonesia, and assuming that it is sort-of effective (leading to rudimentary understanding), your concern seems only to apply to those who don't have such schooling. It seems somewhat unlikely that *many* of the less-schooled (or other-schooled) would have an interest in measure theory, abstract algebra, and set theory. Or would have the opportunity/qualifications to undergo "a first class education in Mathematics".

Comment: Srinivasa Ramanujan is an example of the kind of people that I am thinking about. Although, I am not sure if he learned mathematics from books written in English. If so, then I think the question is answered it is not so important to learn Mathematics in your first language, because Ramanujan  was very successful in Mathematics. Although, since he grew up in India during a time in which it was still colonized by the British, he luckily would have been exposed to  a lot more English than say some one from Indonesia.

Comment: @JimmyJackson Bad example. "Just before the age of 10, in November 1897, he passed his primary examinations in English [...]" ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan#Early_life))

Comment: @Tranmission from  Nonetheless, I think he is still a decent example since he was self educated in mathematics. However, it is not a great example since it appears that English would not have been a hindrance to him.

Comment: @JimmyJackson He also wasn't "self-educated" in mathematics in the sense that he didn't have classes, read books, or consulted others.

Comment: False, he did read books in English, this is explicit in your source.

Comment: @JimmyJackson That's what I meant to say (and I think I did; but I don't speak English natively). He did read (English) books. He had mathematics classes and exams. He consulted others.

Comment: Oppps! Sorry! You are correct I though you said *was* not *wasn't*. I stand corrected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11552/discussion-between-jimmyjackson-and-transmission-from)